# Reload nuxt config every 24h

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I have a sitemap that is generated with nuxt in my nuxt.config.js file.

This siteMap contains a dynamic part, that's why I would like to regularly reload my sitemap to update it.

So I have this config to generate the sitemap when building my app:

```
sitemap: {
path: '/sitemap.xml',
sitemaps: [
  {
    hostname: 'https://test.fr',
    path: '/sitemap-fr.xml',
    exclude: ['/*', '/it/**', '/es/**'],

    routes: async () => {
      return await axios.get('http://localhost:8080/fr/article/active')
        .then(({ data }) => data?.body?.map(article => `/fr/actualite/article?titre=${article.article.url}`))
    }
  },
  {
    hostname: 'https://test.es',
    path: '/sitemap-es.xml',
    exclude: ['/*', '/it/**', '/fr/**']
  },
  {
    hostname: 'https://test.it',
    path: '/sitemap-it.xml',
    exclude: ['/*', '/fr/**', '/es/**']
  }
],
generated: {
  done() {
    cron.schedule('*/5 * * * * *', async () => {
      console.log('Test');
    });
  }
}
```

},

And to regenerate it, every 24 hours for example, I tried to use node-cron but without success

Do you have an idea ?

Comment: `I tried to use node-cron but without success`, more details are very welcome here.

Comment: @kissu I edited my code, as you can see, nuxt-sitemap offers hooks. I tried to use it but without success. I don't know if this is the right solution

Comment: So you're using this specific one? https://github.com/kelektiv/node-cron Where do you host your app? Also, is it SSG or SSR?

Comment: I use this one : https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-cron, for the moment my app is local and ssr is activated

Comment: I doubt you can just dump a cron scheduler into the Nuxt config like that. A cron is more of a system/runtime thing, not a meta-framework config scope. Because you need your platform to go and run your code for you at given intervals. If you are doing SSG and you wish to host it on Netlify, you could [do that](https://docs.netlify.com/functions/scheduled-functions/#getting-started) for example so that way there is a running function to re-generate your sitemap. You could also have a webhook to redo that for you once hosted. Right now, try to run a local cronjob in your UNIX system.

Comment: Are you using nuxt 2 or nuxt 3 ?